# Access Network Share from Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am new to Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi.
I try to access a Network Share and save a file but so far i had no luck.
I tried hours and was searching the web but could not find a solution.
Maybe someone did it already
Would be very happy for help
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not natively supported by Windows IoT.

The closest term I can think of is [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx), but network shared folders don't seem to be included.

However, the workaround you can try is using [FilePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), when browsing the filer, type the network shared folder address in the address far, see if you will get any AccessViolation exception when reading/writing files.

Update, FilePicker does not seem to work either!

Also, I've tried node.js to access network shared smb files, still does not work with Windows IoT.

So far, the answer seems impossible to me.