# Windows 10 IOT Network File

Tags: file-sharing, windows-10-iot-core

i'm trying to access videos from local network with Windows 10 IOT Core.

I Have added Permissions:

- internetClient
- privateNetworkClientServer
- internetClientServer
- enterpriseAuthentication
- videosLibrary
- removableStorage
- remoteSystem

FileTypeAssociation are set in manifest.

folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync() return null:

```
            var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            //folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.HomeGroup;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mpg");
            StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByTitle);
```

this throw a fileNotFountException:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\192.168.0.10\videos\TestVideos\");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("video1.avi");
```

the codes work in debug x86 (windows 10 App), but dont on the ARM(RT) (Windows 10 IOT)

As i can understand, they are some limitation for security. Its there a way to disable this security? Or is it possible to write a library to access files?

tanks!

windows IOT version : 10.0.14393.448

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Network: Ethernet Cable

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529154/access-network-share-from-windows-10-iot-for-raspberry-pi/40542825#40542825

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090669/how-to-access-network-share-from-raspberry-pi-running-iot-core-in-uwp-app

Comment: I have readed the 2 question above before posting mine